# Is there a way to create the forestplot in R metafor, which presents only subgroups and their pooled estimate?

Tags: meta-analysis

For my data, there are essentially two subgroups: Subgroup A and Subgroup B. Is there a way for me to plot the pooled effect three groups:

- Subgroup A
- Subgroup B
- Total effect (Subgroup A + Subgroup B)

Comment: It is hard to answer this without knowing what you tried and why it did not do what you expected. In any event it is off-topic here as programming questions are better asked on other sites. Try the R mailing list for meta-analysis https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis// but you will need to show much more detail otherwise the response is going to be: calculate them and plot them with forest() which is not going to help you.